# jsf myfaces 2.2 failure

Tags: apache, jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I think I have found an error with the current (snapshot) JSF 2.0 Myfaces 2.2 Version; I think I am not the only one having this issue:

when I want to create a link with the following style:

```
<h:link outcome="../../test" />
```

I get following error:

> PM org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.util.OutcomeTargetUtils
>   getOutcomeTargetHref Warning: Could not determine NavigationCase for
>   UIOutcomeTarget component {Component-Path : [Class:
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: ..

When i try it with an old snapshop version (e.g. 2013-04-24), the links are created correctly, also when the outcome-site is in the same folder as the linking file.

anyone else having this problem or is there a way to fix this? I dont't want to switch back to the old version because it has much more serious problems than this link issue

Comment: I have confirmed it works with 2.1.13 and it doesn't with the latest snapshot. Probably it is a bug in the navigation algorithm, because it passed through a big modification by the introduction of Faces Flow. I created [MYFACES-3839](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3839) to fix it.

Comment: thanks. hope it will be solved soon

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug caused by the new JSF 2.2 spec, which enforces the use of ResourceHandler.createViewResource(...), and that code internally has a check to avoid ../ or ./ in the resourceName. It has been fixed on [MYFACES-3839](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3839).